# Can I build an iOS or android app using only famo.us?

Tags: ios, famo.us

I'm assuming that I would need to build some wrapper or shell in obj-c (for iPhone) to interact with notification, vibration, and other iPhone APIs right? It seems like famo.us would allow me to build an app that can run on any mobile device, with just a device-specific shell.  Taking it further, would it be feasible to build generic famo.us app shells (one for each device type) that anyone could use to build a completely device-agnostic app where the code is exclusively js and famo.us?  I'm thinking it would just be a facade layer where you could query what features were available on the device, send commands to things like vibrations etc., subscribe to events or whatever.

Does something like that exist?  Is it even possible?  I couldn't find anything on Google and famo.us is so new I wasn't sure if it was out there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I am not familiar with PhoneGap.. solutions like such, will allow you to write apps with html, css, and JS, and create executables for native applications across many of the platforms. Famo.us has announced that 'phonegap type' solution will be created to fully utilize and standardize the production of Famo.us apps to OS specific native apps. From the FAQ.. under the a section of the question 'How do you make money?'

*Cloud services are PAID but OPTIONAL.
Famo.us will provide cloud services associated with running
and deploying apps—things like wrapping, hosting, analytics,
monitoring, A/B testing, and other related services.
These will be optional cloud services that you can add to your account.
If you don’t want our services, you can always choose your own.*

Here as well you can see the hint of Famo.us providing a native wrapping service for apps. You may just have to wait for now though.

The link to that Doc is here..
https://docs.google.com/a/katabatic.tv/document/d/1aC461kM855a66SzFT_TG8sHpQxqDWy-4yH2XfLBxtTk/edit#heading=h.6es9klfdev6

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

I've used Crosswalk to bundle with my Android Cordova apps and the performance increase is definitely noticeable. https://crosswalk-project.org

It increases app size, from around ~2mb to ~18mb, but the performance is worth it. Makes the app more performant on older Android versions (4.2, 4.3)

Comment: What are the reasons behind using this project ? I'm not really sure if I understand how it is different to cordova itself. It uses latest Blink for rendering or what ?

Comment: It's bundling the latest version of Chromium into the app, instead of using whatever version is native to the OS version. Not as noticeable with Android 4.4+, since it uses a more recent version of Chromium, but older Android versions are much more outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Phone Gap and Cordova, work with famo.us today. You will however get worse performace, specifically on Android, as Cordova and PhoneGap use an old version of chromium.

Comment: Maybe not for Android 4.4+ http://stackoverflow.com/a/18836336/741741